# Specify color of symbols for group levels in panels of a conditioned scatterplot matrix made with splom?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, lattice

How do I specify the color of group levels in panels of a conditioned `scatterplot` matrix generated using `splom`? I can do so in the key, but I find no arguments for symbols in panel.pairs.  Not only does key not match panels, colors assigned to group levels should be `male=blue`, `female=pink`.

```
dput(head(dfSO,20))
structure(list(MHI = c(67460L, 89033L, 61836L, 49853L, 88772L, 
                       105107L, 94744L, 56061L, 49435L, 68027L, 152673L, 56408L, 
                       74493L, 53048L, 62485L, 96712L, 90211L, 81249L, 
                       111576L, 102231L), 
               gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                  .Label = c("female", "male"), 
                                  class = "factor"),
               happy = c(4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3,
                         2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2)),
          .Names = c("MHI", "gender", "happy"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
          class = "data.frame")
library(lattice)
super.sym <- trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol") #where I can customize key
splom(dfSO, groups=dfSO$gender, subset=TRUE, panel=panel.superpose,
      key=list(title="By Gender", columns=2,
               points=list(pch=super.sym$pch[1],col=super.sym$col[1:2]),
               text=list(c("male","female"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

When changing graphical parameters in lattice graphics, my favorite approach is to pass the parameters to the **`par.settings`** argument. This changes the graphics settings for the current plot but doesn't alter the global settings found with `trellis.par.get()`.

(I would also change the `key` argument to `auto.key`.)

You were on the right track with the `superpose.symbol` settings! The order of the grouping variable levels (`male` and `female`) determines which color gets assigned to which level. Since the levels are generally ordered alphabetically, `female` will get the first color.

First, create an object with the desired graphical parameters:

```
myPars <- list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = super.sym$pch[1], col = c("pink", "blue")))
```

Then pass those to `splom` via the `par.settings` argument (notice the altered `key` as well).

```
splom(dfSO, groups = dfSO$gender, subset = TRUE, panel = panel.superpose,
    auto.key = list(title="By Gender", columns=2),
    par.settings = myPars)
```